# Bug in xcode 6.3 static analyser or bad memory management?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, clang, ivar

I have an old app (NON ARC) which runs fine.
Instruments does not report any leaks when I run it.

When I build and analyse, XCode reports several issues (all of the same type) which seems to be false positive :

- I have a subclass of UIView.
- in the .h of this subclass, I declare an ivar named "test" :

  UIView test;
- In the .m, I initialize this ivar :

  test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
- then I add it to self as subview :

  [self addSubview:test];
- then I release it :

  [test release];
- And just below, when I attempt to modify test, for example :

  test.frame = CGRectZero;

...Xcode finds a memory related issue : "Reference-counted object is used after it is released".

For me there's no issue here.
What do you think of this ?

Here is some screenshots :

[image]

[image]

[edit] 2015.07.03 Seems that XCode 6.4 solves this issue.

Comment: Same here - with 6.3 I'm suddenly seeing loads of (IMHO) false positives…

Comment: Same here, new with 6.3